# Validate dropdown item does not occur more than once in a list of dropdown fields with the same id

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form where the user can add as many rows as needed. Each time they are expected to select a different option from the dropdown list provided. At the moment there is no validation to stop them selecting the same value multiple times.

[image]

Each row is a "ResourceCount".
The ViewModel has an IList of ResourceCountViewModel, so each row is being added as an item to the list.

The ResourceCount view model consists of an "id" to store the dropdown value selected and a "quantity" for the number field.

I can't think of a way to use the Compare annotation in this scenario.
How can I implement appropriate validation for this?

EDIT:
There is lots of good advice in the accepted answer. I went with a simple check in the controller post action:

```
if (resourceCounts.Count != resourceCounts.Where(d => d.Id!= 0)
                                          .Select(x => x.Id)
                                          .Distinct()
                                          .Count())
{

ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You can't select the same option more than once");
//etc.

}
```

Comment: you'd probably have to write your own custom validation to iterate the list and check each value, I guess. You could also employ some Javascript to restrict what's in each dropdown, based on what's in the others, to make it less likely that the incoming data would contain errors.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks very much for your input. Could you provide further help for the custom validation?
Unfortunately if I use javascript to remove "on-call" option in the second dropdown, that then presents an issue in the example scenario that the user deletes the first row (there is a delete button at the end of each row.) The second dropdown would then need to have on-call option back in it. And in any other dropdowns added to the page where on-call has not been selected. It's unlikely the user would run into this problem but it's a bit messy regardless. Was hoping there was an easier way out!

Comment: You'd have to write some js, called upon deletion, to work out which dropdowns no longer contain the correct options. Should be relatively straight foward once you figure out your logic. Tip: Write down the flow on paper and then convert to code.

Comment: @MrJF that's literally what I just started doing; now struggling with the "convert to code bit" :)

Comment: I know that feeling! You might be best trying a simple implementation to just do a small part, like populate the list. Then try adding and removing items. Then keep incrementally making it do more stuff!

Comment: "then presents an issue in the example scenario that the user deletes the first row " ...why's that a problem? In the delete action, capture the value in the dropdown before you remove the element and then re-enable it in all the others. It's more code, but it's not really a problem as such, as far as I can see

Comment: Anyway, you can google lots of stuff about custom validation, including some Nuget packages which supply pre-built methods to make this kind of thing easier, plus some standard MS stuff. Have a look around and then try something, if you get stuck edit this to be a more specific question about your issue

Comment: @ADyson an issue in the sense you can spend far too much time writing much complex code that isn't worth it and may even come back to haunt you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply not possible using a `ValidationAttribute` (either in-built or custom ones) and MVC's unobtrusive client side validation.

Validation attributes are applied to properties of a model (your class), and the context in which validation is checked is for that instance only - it has no knowledge of other instances of the model within the collection, therefore it cannot compare other instances.

Conversely if you apply a `ValidationAttribute` to a collection (e.g. `List<T>` property), unobtrusive validation will not work because the `data-val-*` attributes necessary to add rules to the `$.validator` could only be generated if you include an input for the collection property (as opposed to each property of each object in the collection) which means `ModelBinding` would fail.

You will need to write your own controller code and scripts to achieve your custom validation.

On the client side, you could handle the `.change()` event of the `<select>` and check if any previous selections match, and if so display an error message. You have not shown your model, or the view, but based on the following html (repeated for each object in the collection

```
<select class="select" .....>
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">On-call</option>
    ....
<select>
<div class="error"></div> // see notes below if you using ValidationMessageFor()
```

then the script would be

```
var errors = $('.error');
var selects = $('.select');
$('.select').change(function() {
  var selected = $.map(selects, function(s, i) {
    return $(s).val();
  })
  $.each(selects, function(i, s) {
    var error = $(this).next('.error');
    var val = $(this).val();
    var index = i;
    if ($(this).val()) {
      var others = selected.filter(function(s, i) {
        if (i != index) {
          return s;
        }
      });
      if (others.indexOf(val) > -1) {
        error.text('Please make a unique selection');
      } else {
        error.text('');
      }
    } else {
      error.text('');
    }

  })
})
```

Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5m57o9o/1/) for a working example.

Alternatively you could hide/show (or disable) options in each `<select>` to prevent the user making invalid selections in the first place, but that becomes more complex if your dynamically adding/deleting items, and/or when your view is editing existing data where the property already has a selected value (I'll leave that to you to ask a new question showing your attempt if you want to implement that).

On the server side, you can check for duplicate values, and if so, add a `ModelState` error and return the view, for example

```
var selected = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0 i < model.Count; i++)
{
    if (selected.Contains(model[i].YourProperty))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please make a unique selection");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        selected.Add(model[i].YourProperty);
    }
}
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}
....
```

or using linq

```
if (model.Select(x => x.YourProperty).GroupBy(x => x).Any(g => g.Count() > 1))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please make a unique selection");
}
```

which would then be displayed in the views `@Html.ValidationSummary()`.

If your using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].YourProperty)` in your view for each dropdownlist, then the above loop can be modified to

```
if (selected.Contains(model[i].YourProperty))
{
    var propertyName = string.Format("[{0}].yourPropertyName", i);
    ModelState.AddModelError(propertyName, "Please make a unique selection");
    break;
}
```

and modify the script to add/remove the message for the `<span>` element generated by `ValidationMessageFor()` (i.e instead of the `<div class="error">` element as shown above)

As a side note, if you want to learn more about how validation attributes in conjunction with client side validation work, I recommend reading [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2).

Comment: Thanks so much for your insight; I went with controller code only to keep it simple, albeit a sacrifice on user friendliness. The fiddle is flawed in that if you select the first two dropdowns as "Option 1" and then then change the first dropdown to "Option 2", the error remains. (I managed to break it with some other combinations as well.)

Comment: @egmfrs, I should have tested the fiddle a bit more ). I have [forked it here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5m57o9o/1/) which should now cater for displaying the correct messages (its quick and dirty, and can no doubt be optimized, which I will try and do in the next few days)