# Can I add a Validation Attribute to a model in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC I have a view that has a model type of `IEnumerable<MyModel>`.

Can I add a Validation Attribute to this model?

Comment: If you did you could not get client side validation (refer also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321261/validate-dropdown-item-does-not-occur-more-than-once-in-a-list-of-dropdown-field/48331946#48331946) for more explanation). What attribute do you want to apply?

Comment: @Stephen I wish to add a custom attribute checking for uniqueness.  I see your point about client side validation.  Reworking the view to have a proper view model is going to be a lot of work, not only in the view, but also in JavaScript.  Part of the learning process, uhhhg...

Comment: Do you mean that `MyModel` has a property whose value must be unique within the collection? (and if so, the link in the first comment explains why that would not be possible using a validation attribute)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke - i appreciate your input - provides me a sanity check.  Yes, the `MyModel` has a property that must be unique within the collection.  I believe to get the behavior I am seeking I will need to refactor the views to use legitimate view models with proper validation attributes.  To get the client side attributes to function I will probably need to create a custom  javascript too.  I have not performed research how to create a custom  jquery.validate.unobtrusive adapter that considers the entire collection...