# MVC 5. custom validation on list items with error message for every wrong one

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, customvalidator

I have a list of objects inside a model view. What I need is to verify uniqueness for the list items but also to get a specific error message next to the wrong item editor. I searched for solutions but no one is returning the specific messages for the wrong items.

simple example:

```cs
class Child{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Parent{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Childrens { get; set; }
}
```

Example case:

the view is rendered with a Parent(parent1) having 3 Children (Child1 Child1 Child2)

How to I get the validator to catch the first 2 Children as not valid and also to get for each an error message in the view, when the form is posted?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what i need by implementing the IValidatableObject interface like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var childrens = this.Childrens;

                for(int i = 0; i<childrens.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = i+1; j< childrens.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (childrens[i].Name.Equals(Childrens[j].Name))
                        {
                            results.Add(new ValidationResult("not unique!", new[] { "Childrens[" + i + "].Name" }));
                            results.Add(new ValidationResult("not unique!", new[] { "Childrens[" + j + "].Name" }));
                        }
                    }
                }

            return results;
        }
```

the trick i didn't know was the possibility to reference a list item in the ValidationResult just like normal ( Childrens[i])

Now, even though the validation is working well. I would like to know if it is possible to do the same thing with declarative validation because it's more reusable and we can manage client side validation.

Any help is welcome

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321261/validate-dropdown-item-does-not-occur-more-than-once-in-a-list-of-dropdown-field/48331946#48331946) will help you understand how to get client side validation in your case (you cannot do it use anything that is built into MVC)